# Why (1)["abcd"]+"efg"-'b'+1 becomes "fg"?

Tags: c, char, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s", (1)["abcd"]+"efg"-'b'+1);
}
```

Can someone please explain why the output of this code is:

```
fg
```

I know `(1)["abcd"]` points to `"bcd"` but why `+"efg"-'b'+1` is even a valid syntax ?

Comment: Yes, someone can. You're statement "I know `(1)["abcd"]` points to "bcd" " is not correct. It dereferences to the '1' element (second slot) of the literal string, and as such is the *value* `'b'`. Now do the rest of the math, and realize `'b'` - `'b'` is 0.

Comment: In short, it's `'b' + "efg" - 'b' + 1`. Smells undefined on first addition.

Comment: @zch I concur. I just did the math; the legality is another issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know `char *p = "abc" +10;` is  UB (even without de. But `char *p="abc"+ 10 - 9;` is also UB? I am not sure if *subexpression* should also be within the bounds. Can't find anything in the C standard. One possibility is the overflow: if the pointer couldn't represent the resulting value subexpression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about the difference between the other two answers. Here's what happens, step by step:

```
(1)["abcd"]+"efg"-'b'+1
```

The first part, `(1)["abcd"]` takes advantage of the way arrays are processed in C. Let's look at the following:

```
int a[5] = { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 };
printf("%d %d\n", a[2], 2[a]);
```

The output will be `20 20`. Why? because the *name* of an array of `int` evaluates to its address, and its data type is *pointer to `int`*. Referring to an *element* of the integer array tells C add an offset to the address of the array and evaluate the result as type `int`. But this means C *doesn't care about the order*: `a[2]` is *exactly* the same as `2[a]`.

Similarly, since `a` is the address of the array, `a + 1` is the address of the element at the first offset into the array. Of course, that's equivalent to `1 + a`.

A string in C is just another, human-friendly, way of representing an array of type `char`.  So `(1)["abcd"]` is the same as returning the element at the first offset into an array of the characters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `\0` ... which is the character `b`.

In C, every character has an integral value (generally its ASCII code). The value of `b` happens to be 98. The remainder of the evaluation, therefore, involves calculations with integers and an array: the character string `"efg"`.

We have the address of the string. We add and subtract 98 (the ASCII value of the character `b`), and we add 1. The `b`'s cancel each other, so the net result is one more than the address of the first character in the string, which is the address of the character `f`.

The `%s` conversion in the `printf()` tells C to treat the address as the first character in a string, and to print the entire string until it encounters the null character at the end.

So it prints `fg`, which is the part of the string `"efg"` that starts at the `f`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Can you find an implementation that does otherwise?

Comment: @AdamLiss: There are C implementatations for systems that use EBCDIC.

Comment: Wow. I wonder if they also have an encoding for Sanskrit.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
I know (1)["abcd"] points to "bcd"
```

No. `(1)["abcd"]` is a single char (`b`).

So `(1)["abcd"]+"efg"-'b'+1` is: `'b' + "egf" - 'b' + 1` and if you simplify it, it becomes `"efg" + 1`. Hence it prints `fg`.

---

**Note:** The above answer explains only the observed behaviour which is not strictly legal as per the C language specification. Here's why.

**case 1:** `'b' < 0` or `'b' > 4`

In this case, the expression `(1)["abcd"] + "efg" - 'b' + 1` will lead to [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), due to the sub-expression `(1)["abcd"] + "efg"`, which is `'b' + "efg"` producing an invalid pointer expression (*C11, 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators* -- quote below).

On the widely used [**ASCII**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set, `'b'` is `98` in decimal; on the not-so-widely used [**EBCDIC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) character set, `'b'` is `130` in decimal. So the sub-expression `(1)["abcd"] + "efg"` would cause undefined behaviour on a system using either of these two.

So barring a weird architecture, where `'b' <= 4 and 'b' >= 0`, this program would cause undefined behaviour due to how the 
C language is defined:

*C11, 5.1.2.3 Program execution*

> The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the
>   behavior of an  abstract machine in which issues of optimization are
>   irrelevant.  [...] In the abstract machine, all expressions are
>   evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need
>   not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is
>   not used and that no needed side effects are produced.

which categorically states that whole standard has been defined based on the abstract machine's behaviour.

So in this case, it does cause undefined behaviour.

---

**case 2:** `'b' >= 0` or `'b' <= 4` (This is quite imaginary, but in theory, it's possible).

In this case, the subexpression `(1)["abcd"] + "efg"` can be valid (and in turn, the whole expression `(1)["abcd"] + "efg" - 'b' + 1`).

The string literal `"efg"` consists of 4 chars, which is an array type (of type `char[N]` in C) and and the C standard guarantees (as quoted above) that the pointer expression evaluating to one-past the end of an array doesn't overflow or cause undefined behaviour.

The following are the possible sub-expressions and they are valid:
(1) `"efg"+0` (2) `"efg"+1` (3) `"efg"+2` (4) `"efg"+3` and (5) `"efg"+4` because C standard states that:

*C11, 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators*

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>   i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

So it's *not* causing undefined behaviour in this case.

<sub>Thanks [@zch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126943/zch) & [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) for digging out the relevant parts of C standard :)</sub>

Comment: While it is correct on any implementation that I can imagine to be practical, technically, `'b' + "egf"` is undefined if `'b' > 4` (one-past terminating 0).

Comment: @zch I am not sure about UB on subexpressions (excluding the overflow case). Read my comment above.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Why would subexpressions be exempt from UB?! The operators associate on the left, so `'b' + "egf"` is evaluated first, which is indeed a candidate for UB.

Comment: zch, it would be undefined if we were to _dereference_ the intermediate result, but performing _calculations_ is perfectly legal and unequivocallyly defined.

Comment: @AdamLiss, C99 6.5.6/8 "When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
result has the type of the pointer operand. (...) If **both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @KerrekSB That makes sense. Since the whole expression can be evaluated at compile time, this may not be UB in practice. Nevertheless, I'll update answer with the potential UB that's there.

Comment: @zch, thanks for the reference. (No pun intended. Well ... maybe.) I've never come across an implementation that complained, but it's good to know it's not strictly legal.

Comment: `char *p = "efg" + 5;`
invokes undefined behaviour even without dereferencing p Bogus, IMHO. Counter-example: a NULL pointer is a valid pointer expression, though thou should not derefereence it. IOW: an invalid pointer _expression_ can **exist**, when not dereferenced.

Comment: @wildplasser See the quote by zch. The pointer expression `"efg" + 5` is invalid. So it is not comparable to `NULL`, which is valid. The best available reference on this is **C11, 6.5.6 Additive operators, 8** which says what are the valid expressions and **..otherwise, the behavior is undefined.** which contradicts with *invalid pointer expression can exist*.

Comment: @BlueMoon: "*Since the whole expression can be evaluated at compile time, this may not be UB in practice.*" -- That's incorrect. There's no such thing as "UB in practice".  The behavior is simply and unconditionally undefined (assuming `'b' > 4`). If a compiler happens to perform some transformation that produces some particular "expected" result, that's just one of the possible consequences of undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson UB happens if the such code happens to be executed. What I meant was if `'b' + "efg" - 'b' +1` happens as `'b' - 'b' + "efg" + 1` (and simplified as `"efg" + 1`) then there's no UB. I have already stated that excluding those possibilities, this is going to be UB anyway.

Comment: @KeithThompson Let's make it clear: 1. UB happens only if the such code is executed (I hope you agree with this). 2. *If* the code is executed as it is with no optimization then there's UB. 3. *If* the code is optimized by the compiler and it happens to come out simply as `"efg" + 1`, it's not UB. That's all I have said and am not sure what's your contention.

Comment: It's unconditionally executed *in the abstract machine*, and that's what determines whether the behavior is defined. More later; I'm typing this on my phone.

Comment: hmm...If *executed on an abstract machine* then it's unconditionally UB as you said. I am happy to be re-word it, but I'd need a reference for that definition ;-)

Comment: @BlueMoon, C99 5.1.2.3/1 "The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an
abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant." /3 "In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics."

Comment: @zch Thanks for the quote. I have re-worded the answer to reflect this and what Keith said.